# Gfycat Api Token generation failing in Postnam

Tags: postman, token, gfycat

I'm trying to make api calls to the gfycat api but the api allways returns 400 Bad Request

I'm using Postman v7.27.1 with the following url:
https://api.gfycat.com/v1/oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=2_yJNBTO&client_secret=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

The Documentation says the method should be POST and thats what I did.

Am I overlooking something obvious? Some header that the does not want?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok my question was a bit of a quickshot but I needed to add a body with the same clientId and secret.

My body now looks like this:

```
{
    "grant_type":"client_credentials",
    "client_id":"2_yJNBTO",
    "client_secret":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
}
```

Additionally the Header Content-Type had to be set to application/json

Hope this helps someone in the future :)